# How to prevent GitHub Actions workflow being triggered by a forked repository events?

Tags: github-actions

It recently occurred to me that the `on pull_request` event for GitHub actions can be triggered by absolutely anyone if you have a public repository.

i.e.:

1. Someone clones my repository
2. They add a `something.yml` file to `.github/workflows` that runs on the `pull_request` event
3. They create a pull request

The action that they specify in a pull request is then run. If you have a self-hosted runner then literally any person on the planet can run shell commands on your server in the context of the self-hosted runner's user.

If this works as I think it does, any human on the planet can run arbitrary code on your server simply with a pull request. I tried this and it seems to be the case.

How can I whitelist hooks that actions can be triggered by on a repository? Or otherwise, how can I safely use Github Actions with a public repository and a self-hosted runner. I have seen the warning... I just assumed that I had to be careful not to accept pull requests from unknown provenance.

Comment: There is [`pull_request_target`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target).

Comment: pull_request_target won't work. I would have no means of forcing that pull requests with new workflows specify pull_request_target and not pull_request

Comment: You're right, I mixed something up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A configuration option was added to help secure self-hosted runners.  If you have a public repository and a self-hosted runner, then you should always enable the option "**Require approval for all outside collaborators**" as seen in the Actions configuration screen below.

The new default is to require approval for all first-time contributors to run workflows.

However, GitHub still recommends that you do not use self-hosted runners with public repositories.  They specifically state [self-hosted runners should almost never be used for public repositories on Github](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#hardening-for-self-hosted-runners)  As also mentioned on that page is to use [CodeOwners](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) to monitor changes to the directory that your workflow files are stored in (.github/workflows).

[image: GitHub Action Configuration]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot. This is how the runners and GitHub Actions was designed to work. If you have a public repository then having a self-hosted runner is really not a good idea. Even the documentation in [§Self-hosted runner security with public repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#self-hosted-runner-security-with-public-repositories) section mentions:

> We recommend that you do not use self-hosted runners with public repositories.

> Forks of your public repository can potentially run dangerous code on your self-hosted runner machine by creating a pull request that executes the code in a workflow.

> This is not an issue with GitHub-hosted runners because each GitHub-hosted runner is always a clean isolated virtual machine, and it is destroyed at the end of the job execution.

Having that in mind, you have two options:

1. Do not use the self-hosted runner unless you really need it. If you need it then make your repo private.
2. Switch to GitHub-hosted runners.

Comment: A good reason to use a self hosted runner is that an organization's network does not allow for ssh connections to servers within that network. It is unbelievable that GitHub Actions are so insecure by default.

Comment: Especially considering how easy this would be to prevent - i.e. just being allowed to disable event triggers.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell:

- It is not possible to disable this on a public repository (free tier)
- On a private repository it's not possible to run an Action on a pull request by default
- If you have GitHub Enterprise, then you can enable workflows from forks

Comment: what if you current workflow does not have a `on: pull_request` trigger? Than any PR won't trigger the CI runs

Comment: You can add a workflow with that trigger as a pull request. (I think that was the problem anyway)

Comment: but if a malicious contributor adds a workflow with `pull_request` trigger it won't get executed (action will not run, since no existing trigger will be fired on that action)

that is my understanding

Comment: I think that would be logical. but at the time of writing this question that was NOT the case. That was exactly the security problem. It took me a while to actually believe it, but I remember testing it and that did happen

Comment: In other words. Don't have self hosted runners on public git repositories

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in the [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif), you can prevent Actions from running on forked repos by using this in your `.yml` file:

```yaml
if: github.repository == 'ORG-NAME/REPO-NAME'
```

Here's a full `.yml` example:

```yaml
name: example-workflow
on: [push]
jobs:
  production-deploy:
    if: github.repository == 'octo-org/octo-repo-prod'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm install -g bats
```

This uses the `jobs.<job_id>.if` conditional to make it work.

This won't prevent people from removing that conditional to make the code run anyway if that's what they want to do, but it can help them from accidentally running that workflow after they've cloned a repo if they have Actions enabled. (I've personally used this in one of my repo's `.yml` files to prevent forkers from activating a script that deploys ReadMe files as a Jekyll site to GitHub Pages for a job that isn't configured for outside repos.)