# What's the proper way to use GitHub Actions with a public repo if we absolutely need to use self-hosted runners?

Tags: github-actions

I have a small project for which we have a couple of GitHub Actions workflows for the standard stuff like build, unit testing, etc. We have on-prem self-hosted runners because we're testing special hardware that wouldn't be available on ephemeral GitHub-hosted machines.

However, I want to:

- turn the repo public (i.e. to open source it)
- continue using my self-hosted runners with GitHub Actions
- not be vulnerable to the security issues that come with doing so

I know GitHub strongly recommends against using self-hosted runners with GitHub Actions on public repos specifically because of security concerns. Specifically, malicious users can fork your repo and create a pull request to the original repo to launch a `pull_request`-triggered workflow (if it exists).

However, from my understanding, it seems that as long as

- You trust any outside collaborators you invite
- Don't have any workflows with a `pull_request` trigger and never plan to make one
- Have the "Require approval for all outside collaborators" option for GitHub Actions configuration turned on

Then we should be safe. However, I'm concerned that I may be missing something or there's another potential exploit that I'm not aware of.

There has been another discussion on this: [How to prevent GitHub Actions workflow being triggered by a forked repository events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64553739/how-to-prevent-github-actions-workflow-being-triggered-by-a-forked-repository-ev)

But no real guidance on those who absolutely need to use self-hosted runners.

There are some possible solutions, but they're all a little clunky:

- A product called https://actuated.dev/, but it doesn't seem to be generally available/popularized yet
- External CI such as self-hosting Jenkins, however this is quite an up-front cost and considerable maintenance load. We'd also have to redo all our pipeline work in Jenkinsfiles
- Create a 2nd private repo which runs the pipelines on the self-hosted runners, but it would then suck to not have workflow code in one place with the product code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, you're not missing anything. There have been bug reports over the years asking about [this piece of documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#self-hosted-runner-security) because it's not really made clear.

The consensus in [this thread](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26722) is the same (no PR trigger, require approval for outside collaborators, and you should be good).